# QT reformat date time string

Tags: c++, qt

I've got a `QString` that contains a date in the following format:

> 2014-03-18 09:30:36

How can i format it to: `HH:mm`?

Comment: You can format it according to documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `QDateTime::fromString` and `QDateTime::toString` methods:

```
QString dateStr = "2014-03-18 09:30:36";
QString fmt = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
QDateTime dt = QDateTime::fromString(dateStr, fmt);
QString timeStr = dt.toString("hh:mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function todayDate(){
    var months = [ "jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun",
       "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec" ];
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth();

    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd;
    }
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm;
    }
    var today = dd+months[mm]+yyyy;
    console.log("Date::::::::::::::::"+today)
}
```

I hope this function of mine helps!!

Comment: The question regards c++ and Qt, not javascript(?).  Also, I'm not sure your code even performs the task that the question describes (converting a string of one date format to a string of another format).