# QDate toString(fromString) -> setText(Label)

Tags: c++, qt, c++17, qstring, qdate

I am new to Qt UI designer. We got a task to read a txt file, get a string out of it, and print it to a label via `QDate`.

So what I need, is to read a string, format it to `QDate`, and then format it to `QString`.

I tried doing it without an instance of `QDate`, but it did not work. The working code with an instance looks like:

```cpp
QDate QDateInstance;

for (int i = 0; i < (int)TravelAgency1.FlightsList.size()-1; i++){
    if (SearchedBooking == TravelAgency1.FlightsList[i]->getId()){
        ui->ID_Output->setText(QString::number(TravelAgency1.FlightsList[i]->getId()));
        QDateInstance = QDateInstance.fromString(QString::fromStdString(TravelAgency1.FlightsList[i]->getFromDate()),"yyyyMMdd");
        ui->StartD_Output->setText(QDateInstance.toString());
        QDateInstance = QDateInstance.fromString(QString::fromStdString(TravelAgency1.FlightsList[i]->getToDate()), "yyyyMMdd");
        ui->EndD_Output->setText(QDateInstance.toString());
```

But I do not really like the declaration of an instance `QDateInstance`. I am guessing, there is a more elegant way of doing it.

Initially I was trying:

```cpp
ui->StartD_Output->setText(QDate::toString(QDate::fromStdString(TravelAgency1.FlightsList[i]->getToDate()), "yyyyMMdd");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `QDate::fromStdString(...).toString()` . This of course still produces a `QDate` instance, just a temporary one that doesn't have a name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QT reformat date time string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22473968/qt-reformat-date-time-string)